# Vagrant not recognizing Powershell version

Tags: powershell, vagrant, cmder

I am currently trying to use Cmder shell to run vagrant but when I'm trying to add vagrant box it spit out the following error:

λ  vagrant box add ubuntu/trusty64

**Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:
The version of powershell currently installed on this host is less than
the required minimum version. Please upgrade the installed version of
powershell to the minimum required version and run the command again.**

**Installed version: N/A
Minimum required version: 3**

My powershell version is 5.1.19041.1023, Wondow 10.

Comment: Not familiar with cmder, if you run vagrant in a local pwsh session does it produce the same issue?

Comment: I found the same issue when I was running in Cmder. I was surprised to see that it works when running in CMD.exe. (I've never seen anything else that would work in one but not the other.)